# Why will a raspberry pi not let you use the Internet?

Tags: proxy

At my school, I am trying to get the proxy to work on a raspberry pi but no luck. `Aquire http
https://username.password@(ip address)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to install [pi-proxy](https://pi-proxy.net), which automatically sets the proxy at startup. (shameless self-promotion)

If you prefer to do it manually, you can set the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environmental variables:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@address:port/
export https_proxy=https://username:password@address:port/
```

Without authentication:

```
export http_proxy=http://address:port/
export https_proxy=https://address:port/
```

If the password contains an exclamation mark, you need to escape it with a backslash. e.g. If your password is `Passw0rd!`, write `Passw0rd\!`.